# Convert Lua finite state machine class from CS50 game into javascript

Tags: javascript, class, lua, state, cs50

I'm trying to convert this Lua finite state machine class into JavaScript, but I don't think I'm implementing the change method correctly. Does anyone have any ideas on how to covert this code into JavaScript?

```
StateMachine = Class{}

function StateMachine:init(states)
    self.empty = {
        render = function() end,
        update = function() end,
        enter = function() end,
        exit = function() end
    }
    self.states = states or {} -- [name] -> [function that returns states]
    self.current = self.empty
end

function StateMachine:change(stateName, enterParams)
    assert(self.states[stateName]) -- state must exist!
    self.current:exit()
    self.current = self.states[stateName]()
    self.current:enter(enterParams)
end

function StateMachine:update(dt)
    self.current:update(dt)
end

function StateMachine:render()
    self.current:render()
end
```

This is what I came up with, but I'm not able to change states correctly.

```
class StateMachine {
    constructor(states={}){
        this.states = states
        this.empty = {
            render: function(){},
            update: function(){},
            enter: function(){},
            exit: function(){},
        }
        this.current = this.empty
    }

    change(stateName, enterParams){
        this.current.exit()
        this.current =this.states.stateName
        this.current.enter(enterParams)
    }
    
    update(dt){
        this.current.update(dt)
    }

    render(){
        this.current.render()
        console.log('render')
        console.log(this.states)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Lua does `self.states[stateName]()`, which is different than if it just did `self.states[stateName]`.

Comment: Your JS line `this.current =this.states.stateName` must be `this.current =this.states[stateName]()`. 1) In JS `obj.name` is not the same as `obj[name]` and 2) missing function call